# MyBatis multiple operations

Tags: sql, select, sql-update, mybatis

I have below `code` to do an update and get the next value.

```
   <update id="updateNextReference">
        UPDATE table_name
        SET value
        WHERE condition
   </update>


   <select id="selectNextReference" resultType="java.lang.Integer">     
        SELECT value
        FROM <<table>>
        WHERE <<condition>>
   </select>
```

Is it possible to perform both operation in a way that I do update and get the value using `SelectKey`.

I tried to add `SelectKey` inside the `update` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the tag `<insert>` instead of `<update>` in your mapper xml file, it will work.

When I tried the same with an `<update>` tag, I got an exception during the reading of mapper files.

```
<insert id="selectKeyTest" parameterType="MyClass">
        <selectKey keyProperty="prop1" order="AFTER" resultType="Long" >
            select col1 from myTable WHERE col2 = #{prop2}
        </selectKey>
        UPDATE myTable 
        SET col1 = 1
        WHERE col2= #{prop2}
</insert>
```

After the update statement is executed, select statement will set the value of col1 to the prop1 property in MyClass. So, in java:

```
MyClass myObj = new MyClass();
myObj.setProp2("2");
myService.getMapper(SelectKeyMapper.class).selectKeyTest(myObj);
String resultOfSelectKey = myObj.getProp1();
```

Comment: But how do I get the value of col1 in java side?

Comment: If you pass a myClass object as a parameter, "prop1" will be a property in this class. After you invoke "selectKeyTest", you can get the value of col1 by getProp1(). Or, you can pass prop1 directly to the "selectKeyTest" by @Param("prop1") String prop1. Again you will have the value of col1 in "prop1" right after you invoke "selectKeyTest".